# Abelian groups having no finite subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

My question is:

> Are there currently any classification (up to isomorphism) of infinite abelian groups having no non-trivial finite subgroup?

It seems many have asked whether an infinite group can have all proper subgroup being finite, but few are interested in the infinite groups without any non-trivial finite subgroup.

I know such group is equivalent to that no non-trivial element is of finite order and the basic examples are $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ and their direct sums, with addition (+) as the group operation. However, what are the other examples and do we know everything about them?

Thanks.

Comment: This is equivalent to being torsion-free. It is waaaaay too vast to have a classification.

Comment: These are just the *torsion-free* Abelian groups.

Comment: If the group is finitely generated, then it is known that this must mean it is a power of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't heard of the word "torsion-free" before. Just knowing there are many other such groups besides the common ones is good to me.

Comment: In [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group) you will see some discussion about properties and theorems regarding torsion free abelian groups. One of the more accessible such theorems found there says that every torsion free divisible abelian group is isomorphic to the additive group of a vector space over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps broadening my horizon.

Comment: Beyond the finitely generated case, there are quite many interesting partial classification result. Notably there's the notion of finite rank. The ($\mathbf{Q}$-)rank is the maximal cardinal of a free family. To have rank $\le n$ is the same as being isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbf{Q}^n$. Torsion-free abelian groups of rank 1 have a nice classification, due to Baer, easy to establish.

Comment: Thanks! I did some searches afterwards as well and I found that the last section of the abelian group [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Infinite_abelian_groups) seems to contain a brief overview of current understanding of infinite abelian groups in general, including the torsion-free case. [Here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1570-7954(00)80041-8) is also a survey article of results in infinite abelian groups in general before 2000.